# How to make a python project downloaded from github as a frame or package?

Tags: python, github

such as i download a python project named x-master from github, which comprise a modul named x, and i want use this project just like this:

```
import x
from x import ....
```

how should i do on windows??? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you have to install it.look and see if setup.py available in project and if use some installation command. you can install it in develop mod or production mod if you want to install it in develop mod use

```
pip install -e .
```

and in production mod

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file you're writing code in is "my_code.py", just save "my_code.py" in the same folder as "x.py".